# Building a dynamically generated configuration UI using reflection on .NET Config Datatypes

Tags: .net, reflection, user-interface, config, dynamically-generated

Has anyone got any experience with / attempted to do this?

We have some reasonably complex XML config for our .NET application and were thinking it would be nice if we could use our config object hierarchy to dynamically build a UI, using reflection and attributes/meta-data from the properties on these objects to present options to user to produce the configuration.

It would be nice to make this quite generic, so we can provide it with any .NET XML config object (within reason) and it would reflect on it and allow it to be populated.

Comment: Well, WPF using XAML has been quite successful... Without knowing what the configuration consists of, what type of UI it is, it's quite hard to come with opinions. =)

Comment: Wasn't really looking for technology options for building the UI in, to be honest. Rather, experience in dynamically generating them from the config objects.

Comment: These config objects - what are they? What do they look like? What do they describe? Do you aim to describe the UI with them or does the configuration already exist in some way? You'd need to be able to extrapolate position (if even as simple as one-after-the-other flow) from your configuration, to place UI elements, and so on.

Comment: They are standard .NET config objects, inheriting from System.Configuration, ConfigurationSectionGroup, ConfigurationElementCollection, ConfigurationElement etc. So they implicitly describe the structure of the XML. The properties define the types of the data then have attributes that can set defaults, validate data and provide various other meta-data as required.

Comment: Ah, so you're meaning you want to create a dynamic UI around the structure of existing data types, not define a UI via XML config. Gotcha. =)

Comment: Yeah sorry, maybe I didn't quite word it that well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about exactly what Config files in .NET are for. They are a place for defining the differences between different **deployments** of your application. So when you talk about dynamically altering config based on coded logic, I think you might have it the wrong way round. It is your code that should be taking its direction from settings injected via configuration.

It seems you are looking to build some kind of config editor? Why do this when Visual Studio has two built in? The Edit Window and the various Configuration Editors, ASP.NET configuration Editor, Microsoft Service Configuration Editor etc.

In my experience, the differences between web or app.config in a Dev environment vs a Test environment vs a production environment will typically differ by just a few settings, such as Connection strings, AppSettings, Message Queue addresses, Service Endpoints, Log4Net settings etc.

Okay, quite a few settings, but in each block of config, there is usually only one or two attributes that differ from environment to environment. The exception to this is IOC config, such as Spring.NET, CastleWinsor or Unity. But even then, these are often exactly the same from environment to environment.

I would encourage you to go away and think about this for a bit. Think about the actual problem that you are trying to solve. Perhaps you are in need of some database driven workflow? I don't know.

I just know that config should not be driven by runtime code. It is a deployment and build-time thing.

Having said that, there are tools such as [ConfigGen](http://configgen.codeplex.com/), which makes generating environment-specific configuration a breeze. Check it out when this is really what you need.